# why does Oracle take another execution path on a view

Tags: performance, oracle, view, oracle10g

We are using a view on a oracle 10g database to provide data to a .NET application. The nice part of this is that we need a number(12) in the view so the .NET apllication sees this as an integer. So in the select there is a `cast(field as NUMBER(12))`. So far so good the cost is if we use a where clause on some fields 0.9k. But now the funny part if we make an view of this and query the view with an where clause the cost goes from 0.9k to 18k.

In the explain plan suddenly all indexes are skipped and this results in lots of full table scans. Why does this happen when we use a view?

The simplified version of the problem:

```
SELECT CAST (a.numbers AS NUMBER (12)) numbers
  FROM tablea a
 WHERE a.numbers = 201813754;
```

explain plan:

```
Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 1  Bytes: 7  Cardinality: 1     
    1 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) TAB1_IDX Cost: 1  Bytes: 7  Cardinality: 1
```

No problem index hit

If we put the above query in a view and execute the same query:

```
SELECT a.numbers
  FROM index_test a
 WHERE a.numbers = 201813754;
```

No index is used.
Explain plan:

```
Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 210  Bytes: 2,429  Cardinality: 347     
    1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE TABLEA Object Instance: 2  Cost: 210  Bytes: 2,429  Cardinality: 347
```

Comment: Most probably because the case eliminates the possibility for Oracle to use an index. But without seeing the actual SQL and the execution plan this is hard to tell.

Comment: Added the queries and explain plans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're applying a function to the column (cast in this case). Oracle can't use the index you have as your query stands. To fix this you either need to remove the cast function from your view, or create a function based index:

```
create table tablea (numbers integer);

insert into tablea
  select rownum from dual connect by level <= 1000;

create index ix on tablea (numbers);

-- query on base table uses index
explain plan for 
 SELECT * FROM tablea
 where  numbers = 1;

SELECT * FROM table(dbms_xplan.display(null,null, 'BASIC +PREDICATE'));

---------------------------------                                                                                       
| Id  | Operation        | Name |                                                                                       
---------------------------------                                                                                       
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |                                                                                       
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| IX   |                                                                                       
---------------------------------                                                                                       

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------                                                                     

   1 - access("NUMBERS"=1)                 

create view v as 
 SELECT cast(numbers as number(12)) numbers FROM tablea;

-- the cast function in the view means we can't use the index
-- note the filter in below the plan
explain plan for 
 SELECT * FROM v
 where  numbers = 1;

SELECT * FROM table(dbms_xplan.display(null,null, 'BASIC +PREDICATE'));

------------------------------------                                                                                    
| Id  | Operation         | Name   |                                                                                    
------------------------------------                                                                                    
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |        |                                                                                    
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLEA |                                                                                    
------------------------------------                                                                                    

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------                                                                     

   1 - filter(CAST("NUMBERS" AS number(12))=1)   

-- create the function based index and we're back to an index range scan
create index iv on tablea (cast(numbers as number(12)));

explain plan for 
 SELECT * FROM v
 where  numbers = 1;

SELECT * FROM table(dbms_xplan.display(null,null, 'BASIC +PREDICATE'));

---------------------------------                                                                                       
| Id  | Operation        | Name |                                                                                       
---------------------------------                                                                                       
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |                                                                                       
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| IV   |                                                                                       
---------------------------------                                                                                       

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------                                                                     

   1 - access(CAST("NUMBERS" AS number(12))=1)
```